# Derivative of a function when it is squared.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Was wondering when you are for example finding $dw/dt$ but you are given a function like $w^2(t)=r^2-2\cos(t)$, when r is some constant, how you are supposed to solve it? Are you supposed to incorporate chain rule?

thanks

Comment: What is the partial derivative of $w(t) = \pm \sqrt{r^2 - 2cos(t)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got $$w^2=r^2-2\cos(t).$$ Now differentiate everything with respect to $t$ to give $$\underbrace{2w \cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}}_{\text{chain rule}}=0+2\sin(t).$$

Now re-arrange this to find $\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}.$

---

Note that $r$ is constant, so $r^2$ is constant, so the derivative of $r^2$ wrt $\ t\ $ is zero.

Comment: awesome, thank you @alexqwx

Answer (score -2):

A derivative, conceptually, is the rate of change.  Constants do not change over the dependent variables.

r is a constant, there for r^2 is a constant.  The derivative of a constant is 0, thus can be effectively ignored.